# I want to get values key from object which is in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of days

```
"selectedDays": [
            "Sunday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday"
        ]
```

This is coming request body, Now I have to map and generate the number of it
so I have one object

```
const Week_mapping = {
  "Sunday": 0,
  "Monday": 1,
  "Tuesday":2,
  "wednesday":3,
  "Thursday": 4,
  "Friday": 5,
  "Saturday": 6
}
```

**Example-1** - Suppose array has Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday.

**Desired Output :**

```
[0,2,3]
```

**Example-2** - Suppose array has Sunday, Monday,Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday

**Desired Output :**

```
[0,1,2,3,5]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use map. i.e `selectedDays.map(key => Week_mapping[key])`

Comment: Have you tried anything? What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as follows using simple `maps()` -

```js
const Week_mapping = {
  "Sunday": 0,
  "Monday": 1,
  "Tuesday": 2,
  "Wednesday": 3,
  "Thursday": 4,
  "Friday": 5,
  "Saturday": 6
}

const selectedDays = [
  "Sunday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday"
]
// The following line will return array in which the elements in
// selectedDays list  will be mapped to their corresponding Week_mapping
const res = selectedDays.map(element => Week_mapping[element])

console.log(res)
```

You can read more about maps [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you aren't already aware about them. Basically, the `map()` takes an function and maps each element of array(on which map is used) to the result returned by the function.

So, the above code can also be written in following way =>

```js
const Week_mapping = {
  "Sunday": 0,
  "Monday": 1,
  "Tuesday": 2,
  "Wednesday": 3,
  "Thursday": 4,
  "Friday": 5,
  "Saturday": 6
}

const selectedDays = [
  "Sunday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday"
]

// The following function will take a week day and return the number corresponding to it
function weekDaysToNumMappings (weekDay){
  return Week_mapping[weekDay];
}

// Now, we map each element from selectedDays to value returned by above function
const res = selectedDays.map(weekDaysToNumMappings)

console.log(res)
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

This will check if no days are selected:

```
let answer = selectedDays && selectedDays.length ? 
             selectedDays.map(key => Week_mapping[key]) 
            : []
```

Comment: Hi Anjiali, it would be great if you could provide context (in a few lines) so all readers can understand why your solution would work